# How to select different formatter based on file type in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, yaml, prettier

Basically, I'm working with Kubernetes, so I need to deal with config YAML file. And prettier is not very good at formatting the YAML file. So, I want to use official formatter YAML for it. Currently, I'm switching back and forth to YAML formatter. But is there any way to set formatter based on file type. For example YAML for .YAML file and for remaining file such as .java, .go etc we can use the prettier.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open your settings.json file by pressing Ctrl + Shift + P, typing "User Settings JSON," and select the first option.
2. In the settings page, search for the [yaml] block. If the block doesn't exist, add it with the following configuration:

   "[yaml]": {
   "editor.defaultFormatter": "redhat.vscode-yaml"
   }

Ensure that the editor.defaultFormatter is set to the desired YAML formatter extension, such as "redhat.vscode-yaml".

Now, Visual Studio Code will use the specified YAML formatter for files with the .yaml extension.